# Proving a Self Financing Portfolio

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

**Question**:

Let $(S_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a stock price process. Assume $u(.,.)$ satisfies the Black Scholes PDE with short rate $r=0$.

Assume that under a risk neutral measure **P**:
$$
dS_t=\sigma_tS_tdW_t
$$

Where $W_t$ is a **P** brownian motion. Assume $\phi_t$ is the stock holding and $\psi_t$ is the bond holding where:

$$
\phi_t=\frac {\partial(u(t,S_t))}{\partial S}
$$
$$
\psi_t=u(t,S_t)-\phi_tS_t
$$
Show that the trading strategy is self financing.

**My Attempt**

We have that $V_t=\phi_tS_t+\psi_tB_t=\phi_tS_t+\psi_t$

Further, $dV_t=\phi_tdS_t+S_td\phi_t+d\psi_t$

and the self financing condition is: $dV_t=\phi_tdS_t+\psi_tdB_t=\phi_tdS_t$

Meaning I just need to show that: $S_td\phi_t+d\psi_t=0$

When trying to evaluation the second term:
$$
d\psi_t=d(u(t,S_t)-\phi_tS_t)=d(u(t,S_t))-d\phi_tS_t-\phi_tdS_t
$$

Is it correct to assume that $d(u(t,S_t))=\phi_tdS_t$??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that 
$$
S_t\,\mathrm d\phi_t+\mathrm d\psi_t=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
\mathrm d(u(t,S_t))-\phi_t\,\mathrm dS_t=0.
$$
Now apply Itô's formula to compute $\mathrm d(u(t,S_t))$, and note that by the Black & Scholes PDE,
$$
\frac{\partial u(t,S_t)}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_t^2 S_t^2 \frac{\partial^2 u(t,S_t)}{\partial x^2} = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've solved it now. I wasn't familiar with that final result